# URLOpenPullStream - How to get the stream size

Tags: c++, url, download

I'm using IBindStatusCallback and URLOpenPullStream to download data asynchronously. I'd like to allocate the data buffer before the data arrives.

Is there a way to retrieve the Stream size or to read the Stream header so I can allocate a buffer with the proper size?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, `IBindStatusCallback::OnProgress` will be called, `ulProgressMax` will be non-zero, and will actually correctly represent the size of the data.

In many (perhaps most) cases, however, you can't know the total size until you download the whole response. There are two reasons for this:

1. The server doesn't report `Content-Length:` header, but instead uses chunked encoding. There is simply no information up front about how large the response will eventually be.
2. The server does report `Content-Length:` header, but also uses `gzip` compression or similar. `Content-Length:` reports the size of compressed data, and that's what you'll get in `ulProgressMax`. But UrlMon automatically decompresses and reports the actual decompressed data to you, so `ulProgressMax` will be too low. Here again, there's no information about the eventual size of the (uncompressed) response until the whole thing arrives.

Comment: Ah. I see. So my best strategy is use ulProgressMax if available and allocate that much but don't assume this is the actual max and be ready to allocate more as needed. Thanks.

Comment: Or, just ignore `ulProgressMax` and be ready to allocate more as needed. No reason to implement two different strategies.